# SpeechRecognitionEngine Spoken and Recorded do not match

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5, speech-recognition

I am using `SpeechRecognitionEngine` to recognize information being spoken by a user. The method will be running on the client's computer and it is working just fine and recognizing text almost like I want it to. So I'm happy.

However, I want to be able to do some processing of the wave file on my server. Right now I am testing on my local machine and when I use the `SetInputToWaveFile` method on the Recognizer, and pass the same audio clip back through (the one recorded by the engine originally) it does not give anything close to the original matches (or alternates).

For example:
User speaks and recognizer returns the phrase: "Hello how are you today" with 10 alternates.
Wave file is saved and then passed in through using `SetInputToWaveFile` (or `SetInputToAudioStream`). The recognizer will return a phrase (usually one word) that is nothing like the spoken text, example "Moon" along with ZERO alternates.

Often, when doing this, the recognizer will not raise the `RecognizeCompleted` event. It will however sometimes raise the `SpeechHypothesized` event, other times the `AudioSignalProblem` occured.

Shouldn't passing the audio clip that was captured from the recognizer results, back through the same recognizer, return the same matches?

Original:

```
Private _recognizer As New SpeechRecognitionEngine(New CultureInfo("en-US"))

_recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars()
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(New DictationGrammar())
_recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
_recognizer.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
_recognizer.MaxAlternates = 10
_recognizer.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)       
Dim result As RecognitionResult = _recognizer.Recognize()
Dim aud As RecognizedAudio = _result.Audio 'This is the audio that gets saved
aud.WriteToWaveStream("mypath")
```

(I've removed some of the logic code in between that pulls out the results, and does some processing)

Now trying to pull out from the Audio file:

```
_recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile("mypath")

'Doesn't work either
'_recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(File.OpenRead("mypath"), New SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono)) 

Dim result2 As RecognitionResult = _recognizer.Recognize()
```

The recognition/matches from result and result2 are not even close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually set the speech audio format info, and now it works perfectly.

```
_recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(File.OpenRead("mypath"), New SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, Nothing))
```